# pep8, autopep8 and imports at the end of file

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pep8, autopep8

I'm using Eclipse with plugged [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/) and I found it it very helpful. It's saving a lot of my time from fixing code style by hands. But for some coding patterns I don't know how to avoid pep8 rules I don't want to use. For example using Django (1.5.4) I need to connect signals of installed application. I always use `import signals` at the end of `models.py` file. But pep8 doesn't allow to use [imports at end of file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). `# noqa` comment doesn't helps. I can not put `import signals` to the top of the models.py file, because in signals I use some models still not defined on that moment.

What can you suggest in this situation? May be there is more appropriate way to connect signals?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, everything in PEP8 is a recommendation, not a hard-and-fast rule. If your code needs a certain structure, you should feel free to ignore the recommendation.

That said, importing signals at the end of your models file feels a bit strange. Rather, import both models and signals from a separate file that is itself imported at startup. The app's `__init__.py` file might be a good candidate, or you can use the new [AppConfig functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/) in 1.7.